# Rolling of log file through RollingFileAppender Not Working Properly

Tags: java, log4j, logback, rollingfileappender

I am using `ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender` and with that using **time and size both rolling policy** but some time it misbehave and don't do renaming properly.

For example: if my logfile name is hotel-soa.log for current day it's size reached to 1GB it should be renamed as `hotel-soa.2015-09-18.0.log` and another `hotel-soa.log` should be created and logs should be log in that file only then on the end of day it also should rename as hotel-soa.2015-09-18.1.log.

***But sometime hotel-soa.log stop before reaching to size limit and hotel-soa.log.1*** created which is also become current log file.

See below data:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1   491K Sep 18 09:08 hotel-soa.log

-rw-rw-r-- 1   345M Sep 18 11:12 hotel-soa.log.1
```

Which should be:

```
rw-rw-r-- 1   1024M Sep 18 11:08 hotel-soa.2015-09-18.0.log

rw-rw-r-- 1   491M Sep 18 11:08 hotel-soa.log
```

I am using below configuration please help

```
<appender name="LOGS"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <File>/opt/tomcat/tomcat7/logs/hotel-soa.log</File>
    <append>true</append>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>/opt/tomcat/tomcat7/logs/hotel-soa.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                    <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 1GB -->
                    <maxFileSize>1GB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <MaxHistory>50</MaxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <Pattern>%d %-5p [%thread] %c{10}:%line:[pos=%X{IDContext},%X{ID},%X{Token}] - %m%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```